# Remap console log function caller origin in chrome

Tags: javascript

Any time you `console.log` something, on the right side of the console it'll have the origin and line number, like so:

[image]

(see `index.ts:5`).

My app logs things in multiple places, and it would be useful to be able to change what the stack hint is on the right hand side. Right now, for development, they all say `DeveloperLoggingUtils.js:55`, because that's the file that logs the strings to the console instead of sending them to the server. Is there a way to change it so that it's location is known? For instance, if I'm using my dev logging class in `TestButton.js`, and calling it in componentDidMount, is there a way to show `TestButton.js` on the right side?

Comment: No, there's not. Apart from using `console.trace`.